# How to add multiple items to cart?

Tags: 6, ubercart

I came across this other question and wondered whether it was compatible with Drupal 6/UC 2:  [Add multiple items to cart](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22987/add-multiple-items-to-cart-ubercart-3-0)

I would like to create a page that shows the thumbnail and title of all products in a category, with a checkbox next to each one. Then, when a shopper checks three, four, five products and clicks "add to cart", those products are all added to the cart.

Or... even better would be if the product automatically gets added to the cart when they click the checkbox, and they can then click a link to go to the cart and finalize their order after they have added all of the products they want... but I know that may be asking a bit too much. ;)

I'm thinking it would be nice for the mobile environment too... the phone/tablet user could simply tap-tap-tap the products they want and then proceed to their cart.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 0):

For a list with checkboxes I suggest looking at [this issue about using Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/node/548812).